# Trying to get pymediainfo to work

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this [module](https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to work
I installed pymediainfo but i keep getting this error:
"ImportError: No module named 'bs4'"

It says this on the module docs:
"This is a simple wrapper around the MediaInfo command line interface, which you can find at the MediaInfo project site found at http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/

Beyond that requirement, this simple library should work with the standard Python library, as it’s only dependancies are subprocess and xml.dom"

If i don't need any other libraries how do i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency referred to in the OP, *bs4* is beautifulsoup version 4., a python library for querying markup ([beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)). Beautifulsoup requires a parsing library, [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is probably the best option, and is certainly the fastest.